# Get full groups for each element

Tags: java, regex

I have a long text full with useless elements like brackets, spaces, numbers, and I need to parse the same values for every house I'm encountering. I don't always have the same amount of rows in each group. Here's part of the text I have:

```
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]getHouseName: house1
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]price (in doll) [min: 1000, max: 1200]
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]squaremtr (in doll) [min: 75, max:85]
[04:04:04s] [startedRetrieving]sellVal (in doll) [min: 1000, max: 1200]
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:04:05s] [startedRetrieving]rentPrice(in doll) [min: 150, max: 200]
[04:06:04s] [startedRetrieving]getHouseName: house2
[04:06:04s] [startedRetrieving]price(in doll) [min: 1004, max 1100]
[04:06:04s] [startedRetrieving]squaremtr(in doll) [min: 85, max 99]
[04:06:04s] [startedRetrieving]sellVal(in doll) [min: 950, max: 1050]
[04:06:04s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:06:04s] [startedRetrieving]rentPrice(in doll) [min: 150, max: 290]
[04:09:04s] [startedRetrieving]getHouseName: house3
[04:09:04s] [startedRetrieving]price(in doll) [min: 1099, max: 1200]
[04:09:04s] [startedRetrieving]squaremtr(in doll) [min: 90, max: 110]
[04:09:04s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:09:04s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:09:04s] [startedRetrieving]sellVal(in doll) [min: 1100, max: 1300]
[04:09:04s] [startedRetrieving]random useless text
[04:09:04s] [startedRetrieving]rentPrice(in doll) [min: 199, max: 300]
```

and I would like to retrieve every parameter for each group like:

```
HouseName: house 1
MinPrice: 1000
MaxPrice: 1200
SquareMtrMin: 75
SquareMtrMax: 85
SellValMin: 1000
SellValMax: 1200
RentPriceMin: 150
RentPriceMax: 200

HouseName: house 2
MinPrice: 1004
MaxPrice: 1100
SquareMtrMin: 85
SquareMtrMax: 99
SellValMin: 950
SellValMax: 1050
RentPriceMin: 90
RentPriceMax: 110

HouseName: house 3
MinPrice: 1099
MaxPrice: 1200
SquareMtrMin: 90
SquareMtrMax: 110
SellValMin: 1100
SellValMax: 1300
RentPriceMin: 199
RentPriceMax: 300
```

Here's my code:

```
String Name="";
String MinPrice = "";
String MaxPrice = "";
String SquareMtrMin = "";
String SquareMtrMax = "";
String SellValMin = "";
String SellValMax = "";
String RentPriceMin = "";
String RentPriceMax = "";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^getHouseName:\h+(.+)(?:\R(?!price \\(in doll\\) \\[).*)*\Rprice \\(in doll\\) \\[ (\d+)(?:\R(?!squaremtr \\(in doll\\) \\[).*)*\Rsquaremtr \\(in doll\\) \\[\h+(\d+)(?:\R(?!sellVal \\(in doll\\) \\[).*)*\RsellVal \\(in doll\\) \\[\h+(\d+)(?:\R(?!rentPrice \\(in doll\\) \\[).*)*\RrentPrice \\(in doll\\) \\[\h+(\d+)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
for(Matcher m = pattern.matcher(myText); m.find(){
System.out.println("Full match: " + m.group(0));
                for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + m.group(i));
                }
}
```

But I can't find anything. How can I access the result like I described?
Another logic would be to select the groups and interact with them using single regexes for every value, like I already can do, but I can't isolate the groups for each house. How could I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: The strings do not start with `^getHouseName` and for example `price` is also not at the start of the string.

Comment: Even removing the ^ I can't still have any result

Comment: I could for example start like this `^.*\bgetHouseName:\h+(.+)(?:\R(?!.*price).*)*\R.*price\h+\(in doll\)\h+\[min:\h+(\d+,\h+max:\h+(\d+))\](?:\R(?!.*squaremtr).*)*\R.*squaremtr\h+\(in doll\)\h+\[min: (\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/EtT7oR/1 Then if you do that for all the values, you can use the capturing groups.

Comment: This is not working, I'm not printing anything

Comment: I have added a java demo how you might use the group values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the pattern to look for the values further down the string, and use the group values for the variables.

In this part `\[\h+(\d+)` you also have to match the `min:`  part. If you want to scan through the next lines using the negative lookahead with `\R`, you first have to match until the end of the current line first.

```
^.*\bgetHouseName:\h+(.+)(?:\R(?!.*price).*)*\R.*price\h*\(in doll\)\h+\[min:\h+(\d+),\h+max:?\h+(\d+)\](?:\R(?!.*squaremtr).*)*\R.*squaremtr\h*\(in doll\)\h+\[min:?\h*(\d+),\h+max:?\h*(\d+)\](?:\R(?!.*sellVal).*)*\R.*sellVal\h*\(in doll\)\h+\[min:?\h*(\d+),\h+max:?\h*(\d+)\](?:\R(?!.*rentPrice).*)*\R.*rentPrice\(in doll\)\h+\[min:?\h*(\d+),\h*max:?\h*(\d+)\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/puxPaB/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Dq2XuZ)

Comment: thanks! That is working for the first house, but how can I access the other houses? It stops at the end of the first house's parameters

Comment: @thranduil90 My bad, I saw that there are some optional spaces and `:` I have updated the regex and the demo.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much! I'm adapting this to my code now

Comment: What if my values Min and Max are in the form of 12.098765? How do I modify the regex?

Comment: Then instead of using `\d+` you can use `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` and in Java double escape the backslash like `\\d+(?:\\.\d+)?`

Comment: I tried with : `^.*\bgetHouseName:\h+(.+)(?:\R(?!.*price).*)*\R.*price\h*\(in doll\)\h+\[min:\h+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?),\h+max:?\h+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\]` and it recognizes correctly the elements, but then goes from the start of the text